# Javascript to pass information to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have a main page and there are items on the page. When I click "Order Now" on an item, an HTML page slides in over a portion of the page to show the item's details. I am having trouble linking the item clicked with an item inside an array of objects containing the details for each item so I can show the details on the page that slides over.

Here's the main page:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="shop-item">
        <div class="shop-thumbnail">
            <img src="img/originalImage.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="shop-item-footer">
            <div class="shop-item-details">
                <h3 class="shop-item-title">Original Title</h3>
                <span class="shop-item-price">
                    $50.00
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="shop-item-order-btn">
                <a href="ajax/slidingpage.html" class="btn btn-ghost btn-sm btn-pill btn-primary waves-effect waves-light ajax-load-link" data-id="003" onclick="changeImage()">Order Now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The page slides over fine, but I can't seem to get the image to change. The html file that has the info that slides out onto the screen is all encompassed into an article tag. Here's the top snippet of the HTML with the image that I can't seem to get to change.

```
<article class="order-details">
    <div class="order-totals">
       <div class="product-image">
            <!-- ID for image  -->
            <img id="pageOrder" src="../img/Image1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

This is my JS so far that's not working.

```
var items = [{ name: 'Black', cost: '$10.00', id: '001', src: '../img/Black.jpg' }, { name: 'Something', cost: '$10.00', id: '002', src: '../img/image2.jpg' },

function changeImage() {
  for (var i = 0; i >= items.count; i++) {
    if (i = items.count) {
        document.getElementById('pageOrder').src = items.src;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: What does 'items' look like.  It looks as if you are trying to treat it as an array, which it would be `.length` instead of `.count`.  The if is doing an assignment instead of a comparison (`x === y`), and if the items is an array, `items.src` doesn't make sense. EDIT: and `i >= items.count` with i starting at 0 would never be true

Comment: I created an array with keys for the info needed to pass along with the images. I forgot to add the array in the code, but I'm burned out on this issue.

var items = [{
    name: 'Black',
    cost: '$10.00',
    id: '001',
    src: '../img/Black.jpg'
},
    {
        name: 'Something',
        cost: '$10.00',
        id: '002',
        src: '../img/image2.jpg'
    },

Comment: @Taplar The for loop is also starting at 0 and then checking if `i >= length` which will never execute unless the length is 0, in which case, it would be an infinite loop.

Comment: @mhodges actually that'd be an infinite loop, ;)

Comment: Which would make matters worse lol. Like I say up top, not that great with the JS lol.

Comment: @TomG103 so what are you trying to do?  Are you trying to grab the last element in the array, and use that elements src for the image?

Comment: @Taplar Well, true - it would be infinite if the length was 0. Otherwise it will never execute

Comment: I have a page with images on it, when you click a button a section slides over the page to allow you to order the item, but I can't get the image to track the item selected on the main page.

Comment: @TomG103 This is a classic example of an XY problem. Don't ask about your attempted solution, ask about the problem you are actually trying to solve. Describe the behavior you are wanting to happen inside of the click handler (as it relates to your specific dataset/HTML)

Comment: Have you included the js file in both MainPage.html and slidingpage.html?

Comment: When you click the order button, the page that slides out to enter your info should have the image for the item you clicked on. I can maybe do a screen shot?

Comment: and isn't items an array? items.src wont work

Comment: I've placed a script tag on the HTML file (the one that has the info and slides across the main page) at the top, but the entire thing is an article tag, so not sure if I should do that or not. As bad as it sounds, I might just end up having each button link to a different article for each item.

Comment: I honestly just need the src to change. The rest of the info for the items is the same for the most part.

Comment: document.getElementById('pageOrder').src = items[i].src;

Comment: @TomG103 Try out my solution and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, when you click the order button, you can find the item by id in `items` by reading the `data-id` property on the order button that was clicked and then access the properties from that item like so:

To get this working with your specific scenario, you will have to modify some functions that you did not include in your original question, but I dug up from the link you provided in the comments. The code would look like the following:

```
var items = [{
  name: 'Black',
  cost: '50.00',
  id: '001',
  src: 'img/Black2.jpg'
}, {
  name: 'Red',
  cost: '50.00',
  id: '002',
  src: 'img/BloodRed2.jpg'
}, {
  name: 'Desert Fox',
  cost: '50.00',
  id: '003',
  src: 'img/DesertFox.jpg'
}];

// Single Post via Ajax
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var ajaxLoadLink = $('.ajax-load-link'),
    orderBackdrop = $('.order-content-backdrop'),
    orderContainer = $('.order-content-wrap'),
    orderContentWrap = $('.order-content-wrap .inner'),
    orderContent = $('.order-content-wrap .inner .order-content'),
    closeBtn = $('.order-content-wrap .close-btn'),
    orderPreloader = $('.order-content-wrap .preloader');

// Open Order
function openOrder(itemDetails) {
  $('body').addClass('order-content-open');
  orderBackdrop.addClass('active');
  orderContainer.addClass('open');
  orderPreloader.addClass('active');
  orderContentWrap.addClass("loaded");
  setTimeout(function() {
    orderPreloader.removeClass('active');
    // insert data from itemDetails into their respective places on the form
    $(".order-content-wrap .order-details .product-image img").attr("src", itemDetails.src);
    $(".order-content-wrap .order-details .product-image img").attr("alt", itemDetails.name);
    $(".order-content-wrap .product-title").text(itemDetails.name);
    $(".order-content-wrap .price i").text(itemDetails.cost);
    $(".order-content-wrap .total-cost i").text(itemDetails.cost);
  }, 900);
}

// Close Order
function closeOrder() {
  $('body').removeClass('order-content-open');
  orderBackdrop.removeClass('active');
  orderContainer.removeClass('open');
  orderContentWrap.removeClass('loaded');
}

ajaxLoadLink.on('click', function(e) {
  var itemDetails = items.find(item => item.id === $(this).attr('data-id'));

  openOrder(itemDetails);

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

## [Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/xitomakewa/1/edit?html,js,output)

- Code is too long to put in a stack snippet
- Make sure to press "Run with JS" when you load the jsbin

Comment: The page that slides over is completely blank with that code. The div and article segments posted above are separate as they are in different html files.

Comment: @TomG103 You're going to have to post your code that makes the "sliding in" and data population happen.

Comment: .order-totals {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
 .product-image,
 .order-totals-detail {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
 }
 .product-image {
  width: 325px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  > img { width: 100%; }
 }
  .product-title {
    margin-bottom: floor($line-height-computed / 3);
  }
  .order-quantity {
    margin-bottom: floor($line-height-computed / 4);
    > * {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin-right: 6px;
    }
    span { font-size: $font-size-lead; }
  }

Comment: Seems like the movement is in CSS, but as this is a template, who knows lol. I have to attend a company function so I'll be back later tonight to see what is around. I'll share a link where I've been slowly making it on the back end of my soon to be turned off website. When you scroll down, you'll see images of each item in it's color. Hit the 'order now' button below that image and you'll see what I'm trying to do.

http://devwithabeard.com/atak.php

Thanks again everyone for helping. If we can't fix this soon, I'll make html files for each one and fix it at a later date.